# Spacing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, spacing

Lets say I have the following variables:

```
cheques = 1
x = 2
numberOfBACS = 87
```

and so on.

Now in this case it's very simply to see the variables, but add in equations etc... and this section of code can become hard to read.

Through Pycharm I can use spacing to make the code easier to read.  As follows:

```
cheques      = 1
x            = 2
numberOfBACS = 87
```

My question is:  If I adopt this approach for readability will I run into any problems?

Answer (score 10):

Problems from the point of view of Python syntax, no.

But I recommend against doing this, purely from a code maintainability point of view. What happens for example if you now need to add another variable to the list?

```
cheques      = 1
x            = 2
numberOfBACS = 87
ohdearwhatalongvariablenamethisishardlyworthtypingbutnevermind = 10
```

Now you have to edit all the lines, not just the one you've added.

Comment: +1 I also think so, My opinion is to keep it simple.

Comment: +1. On the other hand, it is nice when comments after the commands are aligned. For that purpose, TAB is a nice key. Anyway, I still prefer to set the editor so that it expands tabs to spaces. As Daniel wrote, one should not want to have everythig looking perfectly. It is also questionable whether it helps readability. (Yes for the comments, no for the assignments.)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you stick to pep8 unless you really need an extension.

Which makes for

```
cheques = 1
x = 2
bacs_count = 87
```

As Daniel pointed out, fixed space layout is problematic with any refactoring.